# Scroll down in Ui5 List using growing feature

Tags: sapui5

I want to Scroll down in my Ui5 List automaticly when new Items are added to my JSON-Model.In my List growing and growingScrollToLoad are set "true".
To scroll down automatically I implemented something like this:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
    var Scrolldown = sap.ui.getCore().byId("MasterItem");
    var ul = Scrolldown.$().find('ul');
    var ul_id = ul.attr('id');
    ul.find('li:nth-child(' + (rowCount - 1) + ')').focus();
    ul.find('li:nth-child(' + (rowCount - 1) + ')').blur();
});
```

But since I've activated growing this doesn't work anymore.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: So, do you get an error? Do variables `ul` and `ul_id` have a value, and, subsequently, do both `ul.find` operation yield any results?

Comment: No I don't get errors and the Methods find() do what they should do. But scroll down to the actual end of the List. But then the "growingScrollToLoad" load more elements....

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the list *does* load the new data, but it does not scroll to the end? Is the value of `rowCount` matching the new number of list items?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the Problem. Yes rowCount matches, by the way oModel.getProperty("/modelData").length has the same Value.

Comment: Did you try to execute your code in the console after everything was rendered to see if it is a timing issue ?